# update blob data using service builder classes failed

Tags: java, liferay, blob, liferay-6

I'm using liferay-6.1 CE.I am developing a project for storing the application data as BLOB in DB using service builder.
This is my entity in service.xml

```
<entity name="MyEntity" local-service="true" remote-service="false" table="MyEntity">
```

I have defined my blob data as below in service.xml

```
 <column name="myData" type="Blob"/>
```

I persisted data into db by using code below.

```
long primarykey = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(com.mycompany.portal.model.MyEntity.class.getName())
MyEntity entityobj = MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.createMyEntity(primarykey);
byte[] bytes =String.valueOf(JAXBUtil.getInstance().marshal(appModelAttri, AppEntity.class)).getBytes();
//String.valueOf(JAXBUtil.getInstance().marshal(appModelAttri, AppEntity.class)).getBytes(); has the marshalled xml data of my application
Blob blobdata = new SerialBlob(bytes);
entityobj.setmyData(blobdata);
MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.addMyEntity(entityobj)
```

Persisting to db worked well.But when I tried to update the same record in DB every other fields in my table except the blob data field is updated.

Code for updating Blob data is given below.

```
MyEntity entityobj = MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.getMyEntityByScreenName(PortalUtil.getUser(actionRequest).getScreenName());
byte[] bytes =String.valueOf(JAXBUtil.getInstance().marshal(appModelAttri, AppEntity.class)).getBytes();
Blob blobdata = new SerialBlob(bytes);
entityobj.setmyData(blobdata);
MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.updateMyEntity(entityobj);
```

I dont understand why only Blob data is not getting updated when I call updateMyEntity method.
Is there anything specific with Blob data updation using service builder generated classes?.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for blob updation failure. To solve this you have to set **cachedmodel** to false and call the update method with 2 parameters (entity object and merge ).By doing so you are forcefully making it execute session.saveOrUpdate statement and will skip **session.merge(appModel)** statement in **upadate()** method of **BatchSessionImpl**.

> entityobj.setCachedModel(false);
>
> MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.updateMyEntity(entityobj,false);